# Is there any twitter function for login to application?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to make my twitter users login to my twitter app using a customized login button..
for instance just like Fb.login method for facebook is there any such method in the twitter api that login to app using an api?

This just display a login button

```
T("#signin-btn").connectButton(); //
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of JavaScript libraries for Twitter. You can see some of them here : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#javascript.

There is the bootstrap API made by Twitter too : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt : Consider visiting the link I gave in my answer. On the link (Twitter Bootstrap API github page), it's written : "[Twitter] Bootstrap provides simple and flexible HTML, CSS, and Javascript for popular user interface components and interactions."

Comment: @airdex: Oh, I know what Bootstrap is. But it's definitely not an API that allows you to log in, and "CSS framework" is likely the best description for it, even although it has some Javascript as well.